# Generating a module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

$L$ is a field, $M = L[X]/(X-1) \oplus  L[X]/(X^2-2X+1) \oplus L[X]$ the $L[X]$-module.

How can I show that L is generated by $e1 = (1+(X-1),0,0)$, $e2 = (0,1+(X^2-2X+1,0)$ and $e3 = (0,0,1)$.

If I later show linearly independence, those e are a basis of M.

I am very unsure with those $\oplus $ signs.

Answer (score 1):

You want to show that $M$ is generated by $e_1,e_2,e_3$ as an $L[X]$-module. In general, if $a$ is a generator of $A$ and $b$ is a generator of $B$, then $(a,0),(b,0)$ generates $A\oplus B$. So all you have to do, is to show that $e_1$ generates $L[X]/(X-1)$ and so on, $e_2$ generates $L[X]/(X^2-2x+1)$ and so on.

How does $L[X]$ act on $L[X]/(X-1)$?, that's easy, take $\overline{P(X)}\in L[X]/(X-1)$ (here $\overline{P(X)}$ denotes the class of a polynomial in $L[X]/(X-1)$) and let $Q(X)\in L[X]$, then $Q(X)\cdot \overline{P(X)}=\overline{Q(X)P(X)}$.
It clearly follows that $P(X)=1$ is a generator by definition.